# How to silence logs from additional dependecies when using Lombok @Slf4j

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, lombok

We are using Lombok with the annotation @Slf4j to print our logs to the console as:

```
log.error("Some error")
log.info("Something")
```

However there are a lot of other lines being printed for example from

```
com.amazonaws.request.
org.apache.http.impl.conn.
```

We are using Maven for our dependencies.
I have tried using a log4j.properties similar to this

```
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=OFF
```

But I'm not sure if I have the file in the correct path or why it is not reading it. I tried putting it in src/main/resources or the project root directory and nothing.

I'm adding Lombox as a dependncy as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

and using the annotation @Slf4j

Any advice on how to turn off the logs from the additional dependencies would be appreciated

Comment: Does your project use `Spring`, `Spring Boot`, or other framework?

Comment: Lombok isn't a relevant part of this question; lombok just makes `log` work, it has zero effect on log4j's configuration.

Comment: @yejianfengblue yes we have spring boot, but this I think the class we are using for testing right now runs by itself independet of spring

Comment: @rzwitserloot ohh I though lombock might change the way log4j's is configured, but if not, then something like this:

`log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=OFF
`
in the log4j.properties file should work right? 
I dont understand why our log4j.properties doesnt seem to be getting picked up. I have it under scr/main/resources, should it be somewhere else?

Comment: Spring boot picks log configuration from [`application.properties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels) or from [`log4j2.xml` or `log4j2.xml`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.custom-log-configuration).

Comment: @yejianfengblue when using the debugger to step into the log.info("something") it takes me to a call in logback-classic-1.2.3.jar, does this mean spring is defaulting to logback instead of log4j, or is this something lombok does under the hood but deeper down it its using log4j?
I have the lombok dependency added and Im using the `@Slf4j` annotation so for me it doesnt make sence why it would default to logback

Comment: spring boot uses logback by default. To use log4j2, [exclude spring-boot-starter-logging and add `spring-boot-starter-log4j2`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging). I don't know why this doc snippet is no longer contained in the latest spring boot doc.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging) is worth reading

Comment: Yeah we have implemented basically step 7.1 from the tutorial you shared, but still it seems I get defaulted to logback when the `log.info("An INFO Message");` is called and I added the excludes to spring-boot-starter-logging and nothing. I think this component is runing independetly of spring boot